# please can you what does return -1 and return 1 means here and does is work

Tags: javascript

I want to figure out what return -1 and return 1 did in following code
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_sort_object2

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Please include the code, and your attempts to understand it, in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If car a is in lower alphabetical order than car b then -1 is returned, if it is higher then 1 is returned, and if they are the same then 0 is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Given a sorting criterion, let us consider lexicographical ordering, there can only be three conditions that exist between two letters/number, `a` and `b`.

The condition are as follows:

1. `a = b`/both are equal, return 0
2. `a < b` or `a` occurs before `b`, return -1
3. `a > b` or `a` occurs after `b`, return 1